# How many arguments does a function take?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

How can i get a lambda list specification of a some function parameters, or at least a number of arguments it takes?

For example:

```
(defun a (a b) )
(get-arg-list #'a) ;-> '(a b)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Common Lisp provides the function `FUNCTION-LAMBDA-EXPRESSION` which may be able to recover the source expression, which then includes the lambda list.

LispWorks has defined a function `FUNCTION-LAMBDA-LIST` which returns the arglist.

Many other implementations have some form of `ARGLIST` function in some internal package.

Many Common Lisp users use SLIME, a very clever editor extension for the GNU Emacs editor. It has a backend for Common Lisp called SWANK. The SWANK sources provide all kinds of interfaces to the various Common Lisp implementations, including getting the arglist of functions.

Answer (score 2):

This is implementation specific, but this CLHS function might get you started - http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_descri.htm

Comment: Btw, do you know a library, which would introduce some abstraction level for major implementations?

Comment: Hi Necto, please take a look at the other answers from Elias, and Rainer. (Btw, Rainer has a very nice page, not sure whether it's still online showing all the good glory of Common Lisp)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use the SWANK library which is used by SLIME.

The way to use it is to load SLIME, which is most easily done through Quicklisp:

```
(ql:quickload "swank")
```

Then, you can get the argument list using the following function:

```
CL-USER> (swank-backend:arglist #'a)
(A B)
```

Comment: A little rectification, a can't quickload "slime", because, quicklisp doesn't have it int it's default repo.
But i just can (ql:quickload "swank").

Comment: Thank you. That's very true. It was a typo. I'll fix the post.